# "Yearly meeting", Germany, how common is it to be fired?

Tags: meetings, germany

**Reopen voters: check [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/110465/yearly-meeting-germany-how-common-is-it-to-be-fired#comment342760_110465) comment.**

Recently I had some troubles with one of the bosses of my employer company, and I think he is now working on my firing. Fortunately, other bosses are sympathising with me, but I have no way to know, how do they decide.

It is Germany.

Now I got a meeting invitation to a "yearly meeting". These are held yearly for the employee. Although they are held in practice not so regularly. It is a personal meeting between the employee, the HR co-worker and one of the bosses (last is not always there).

The timing of the meeting invitation roughly passes to the time where it should be held, but it happens surprisingly coincidently after these little "troubles".

Now the HR co-worker wrote to me this in the meeting invitation:

> If you have any questions, say them to me.

It is uncommon - typically, in the case of the meeting invitations, the questions should be asked on the meeting, and not before them, from one of the participiants.

On the previous meeting, only I talked with this HR co-worker. On this meeting, also one of the bosses (who seems liking me) will take part.

Actually, I have only a single question:

> Will you fire me?

However, exactly this is what I can't ask. If they want to fire me, they will say it to me on the meeting, and not before.

But I would like to know the answer. What should I do?

---

<sub>Result: Finally I didn't react, just silently accepted the invitation. It was an ordinary meeting, as usual. The possibility of a firing wasn't even indirectly mentioned. It seems I seriously misinterpreted the power relation between the bosses. The HR worker probably suspected, that I have this fear, and I think he might tried to avoid it with this message. At the meeting I already knew, that my fears were groundless, because also many other co-workers had their yearly meeting at the time.</sub>

Comment: Not sure what you are asking?  is hr suggesting you ask questions to them prior to the meeting or at the meeting. And you should not  be facing firing at your yearly meeting assuming your employer is following best practice

Comment: @Neuromancer Yes, as I wrote, the HR co-worker is suggesting to ask questions *before* the meeting. It is uncommon, particularly in this meeting, but also in the meetings in general. The meetings are for the questions, not induvidual 2-person talks before them.

Comment: Please do take into consideration that firing someone in Germany is not like in the US. There is not "at will" employment and a firing does not come out of the blue. *My guess* is that your worst case scenario is being put on probation if, indeed, you did something wrong. And the advice I always give: Don't be late in getting Rechtsschutzversicherung that covers work related issues!

Comment: @Gray Sheep: Are you still on probation? (Customary in Germany to start a job with some months of probation, with eased firing procedure)

Comment: I´d also advise you to work on your trouble with this boss that has you on notice, as preparation of that meeting. Maybe this site or other resources can help you to **A.** No get emotional at work and subsequently get into a trap that gets you fired. **B.** Place yourself strategically so you can already show (plans for) improvements of anticipated critique.

Comment: @viorel I would be more glad to live in a country with at will employment. Here in Germany, the companies are braindamagedly suspicious to employ somebody. I think a free job market with easy firing, easy employment would be much better for everybody after all. Only the work lawyers are the unneeded part of this country, in my opinion.

Comment: @viorel This is what I've read here on the Workplace SE: Probations are essentially firings with a timeout. If there is a probation, there is no real chance that I will pass it. But I will try to.

Comment: @Daniel No, I am working here since years. But now the company started a re-structuring. The new structure is worser (for me) as the previous one, but it is still much better as anything I've experienced in Germany. But they may think that I don't pass the new structure.

Comment: By 'yearly meeting' do you mean 'performance review'? Additionally, in its current state this is not a question we can answer on this site. We can't know what the rules/regulations/policies etc are in your company so we cannot answer this part of your question. What *could* be answered here is something like "in Germany, what is required to legally be able to fire someone"

Comment: @Cronax I translated it from "Jahrliche Besprechung" on German (I don't know if it makes things more clear for you. Not German and not English are my first language). It is not named as "performance review", although it has a strong flavor as if it would be one.

Comment: @Cronax Additionally, the essence of the question was: "How to ask this important thing from the HR-coworker, while I can't ask it directly.". I think it is an answerable question. It does not depend on company policies, it is a communication thing: he offered me the - uncommon - possibility to ask things from him before the meeting, I had something to ask, but it wasn't something what can be asked directly.

Comment: You can always ask "how did I do this year?" or "are you happy with my performance".

Comment: This question wasn't asked about a specific company, this question was asked about the common customs about a company. I see no reason to close this question, the close voters probably didn't even try to understand it before clicking close...

Comment: I think your HR wants to let you have a chance to defend yourself. That's all. We can't tell you exactly what you should say because we don't know exactly why one of your bosses wants to fire you. It's up to your company what to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the time being, I would propose you stay composed and attend the meeting without questions beforehand, this way you don't spread unnecessary tension or lose face by asking something that is very far from the truth.

You should be mentally prepared for all possible outcomes and be prepared ahead of the meeting(paper trail checked etc) to defend yourself and your work if need be. The fact your sympathizing boss will be the one attending is positive.

p.s. If you really can't contain yourself, you can politely and indirectly ask for the exact purpose/thematology of this meeting to the HR rep since, after all, they welcomed questions. This way you can clear it up or at least be hinted about the direction this may go.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, how do you think that they include me in their future plans?

Comment: @GraySheep We do not know your superiors and we do not know anything about your situation, so we are less qualified to estimate their intentions than you are.

Comment: @GraySheep You re right, from the information you shared, there's no indication of this. I  went over that part in your original question absent-mindedly, hence I corrected my answer to reflect this. All in all, I wouldnt stress about this endeavor especially if its really about lesser issues you re having with the other boss and you re prepared to explain yourself for these in a determinate fashion anyways (IF and thats a big if, this meeting is about those).

Comment: @Leon This boss thinks now that I make everything bad-working what I do. Anything what I say to him, he ignores. For example, if our serverhosting gives to us a bad service, I say it to him, the he ignores it and says that I am working badly. We are after roughly 5 similar cases, and now he simply stopped to work with me together on anything, instead employed a new co-worker, from him he thinks he could do what I "can't".

Comment: @Philipp This is why this question is about, how could I ask this from the HR worker, and not about "what do my bosses think".

Answer (score 8):

If the company wants to fire you, it would be unusual to wait for it until some annual meeting. It would be much more likely that you do something wrong, and get fired shortly afterwards (taking notice periods into account), not during some annual meeting.

PS. If someone asks "Am I going to be fired", the other side will now assume that there must be a good reason to fire you, even if they were not aware of any such reason before you asked. So you *really* hurt yourself by asking that kind of question.

Comment: If the time period between the time of incident leading to them wanting to fire someone and the annual performance review coincide, its not a bad idea to have this talk during the review while allowing them enough time to search for the replacement and tie all loose ends in the meanwhile.

Comment: It appears like the annual meeting was set up after some event that makes OP suspect they might get fired. Also, in Germany, notice periods often are three months or longer. Getting fired quickly is only possible under very specific circumstances (and OP doesn't describe these).

Comment: You normally need a cause for firing someone in Germany. A performance review can serve as a good documentation of such cause!

Comment: @Roland The meeting may be any time, but in practice it happens roughly yearly. I waited it in the next half year. So, the yearly meeting now is roughly in time, but it happens with surprising coincidence after these little events.

Comment: @Roland If they fire me, then the firing period will start at the moment. However, this question is about: "How can I ask this from the HR worker" and not about how the firing process will go, if it will.

Comment: @Daniel Continuous low work quality is a possible cause, and it is their decision, how do they value my work quality. One of the bosses values it continuously very low. Other bosses don't. My opinion is, that no, it is *not* VLQ, but it is not decision.

Comment: @Gray Sheep: Yes, but on such causes as *continuous low work quality* the employer needs to show how it was low quality and how they gave you notice and opportunity to improve. Such a meeting can serve as documentation of giving you notice and it is also common to negotiate goals to where you need to improve.

Comment: @Daniel I have no intent to fight it before a court, my business model is that I make myself useful by good work. However, I think if they fire me on the reason of VLQ, it will be unfair.

Comment: @Daniel I see secondary signatures that may be already data collecting for such a proof.

Comment: @Gray Sheep: If you have troubles with the VLQ issue, I bet you can expect that meeting to be about that and to put you on notice, but not fire you. I also think you approach sounds reasonable!

Comment: @Daniel Of course no one commits any mistake in a many year long work time. They *can* point to my mistakes and problems. But I can surely say that the recent problems with this boss are unfair from his side (and they have probably a personal reason - he became a boss just recently, and I handled him further as a co-worker. It was a serious mistake from my side, I admit that. He now probably feels on the personal level that he can't handle me).

Comment: If someone asks "Am I going to be fired" they might consider it as a joke and laugh.

Answer (score 0):

If they know already they want to fire you why would they need a meeting for this. A letter would be sufficient.

But maybe they think about that maybe they want to fire you and this meeting is about evaluating you before they make a decision. So make sure you are well prepared.

Comment: No decent company fires through a letter. This is one of the times when a manager is morally obligated to deliver the news in person. If they don't then they are a coward. If a company lets a manager get away with this act of cowardice, then it is a bad company to work for because there will be plenty of other things that they are too cowardly to properly address. I would move on immediately If I knew a company behaved this way.